# How to create continuous multidimensional arrays in D, which could be interfaced with C code?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, interface, d

I got interested in the D language and started learning it due to impression that it can support easier and more efficient coding than C or C++, while retaining the ability to use code written in these other languages.

However, trying to construct a 2D array I observed this:

```
auto a = new double[][](1000,3);    // clean and seemingly elegant
a.length = 0;                       // To fill the array by ~= operator
a ~= [1, 2, 3];                     // fill the first row
writeln(a);                         // -> [[1, 2, 3]]  (OK)
writeln(a.capacity,a[0].capacity);  // -> 1 3  (should be 1000 3)
```

It already feels wrong, as I explicitly expressed the wish to reserve memory for 1000x3 numbers. Still, both Digital Mars D and GCC gdc compilers produce the same result.

So to make the array really two dimensional, I added another row.

```
a ~= [3, 4, 5];                     // add another row
writeln(a);                         // -> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] (OK)
writeln(a.capacity,a[0].capacity);  // -> 3 3
```

This could be acceptable if it meant that the contents of `a` occupied a solid block of memory with the size of `3*3*double.sizeof` and row-major layout. But more surprises were on the way - when I wanted to check the layout of this array from the C point of view:

```
double* p = &(a[0][0]);             // get a C-like pointer to the data
for(size_t i=0; i<20; i++) {
    writef("%.0f ", *(p+i));        // should be: 1 2 3 4 5 6 nan nan ...
    }
writeln();
```

I got puzzling results, and different among compilers. Dmd with libphobos2 (version 2.071.0) said:

```
1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 4 5 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

but with gdc (GCC version 4.8.4) the same code printed this:

```
1 2 3 0 nan nan nan 0 nan nan nan 0 nan nan nan 0 nan nan nan 0
```

Oops. This is neither usable nor portable. Either the array is not continuous at all (so I read some other memory), or or both implementations are buggy because initialization with `nan` should be guaranteed. OK, I know already that I can use `malloc` and do everything like I would do in C, but then I don't see the advantage of learning another huge beast a language with its own quirky hacks.

Is there a clean way to make continuous multidimensional arrays with C layout, without loosing the advantages of D like memory management, ranges, slices, algorithms, etc?

**Edit:**

After the answer of @weltensturm I fixed my bugs and I did a little more testing. I actually need a dynamic array, because I read the numbers from FIFO and I don't know a priori how many rows to expect. This code apparently works:

```
auto as = new double[3][0];     // Inconsistent w/C: this is 0 rows by 3 columns
auto ad = new double[][](0,3);  // also 0 x 3
as ~= [1,2,3];  as ~= [4,5,6];
ad ~= [1,2,3];  ad ~= [4,5,6];  // I can append to both
writeln(as);                    // -> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
writeln(ad);                    // -> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
writefln("as capacity: %dx%d", as.capacity, as[0].capacity);
                                // -> as capacity: 2x0
writefln("ad capacity: %dx%d", ad.capacity, ad[0].capacity);
                                // -> ad capacity: 3x3
double* p = &(as[0][0]);
for(size_t i=0; i<6; i++) writef("%.0f ", *(p+i));  // -> 1 2 3 4 5 6
writeln();
p = &(ad[0][0]);
for(size_t i=0; i<9; i++) writef("%.0f ", *(p+i));  // -> 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0 0
writeln();
```

Both `as` and `ad` are actually dynamic and are resized on append, but they do behave differently - look at the capacities after the appends.

So now the question is, can I rely on the behavior of any of these alternatives? Is it guaranteed by the language at least for the `new double[3][0]` syntax? Is it possible to guarantee the layout and continuity for the "dynamic" (`new double[][](0,3)`) array, provided I know what *not* to do (e.g not changing the `length` property directly)?

Comment: You have a dynamic array of dynamic arrays. You get a continuous memory footprint need to have the inner dimension static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using dynamic arrays. Note that they have a length value that can be set, which is shown in your GDC example as zeroes interrupting `nan`s. Because you set that length value to zero, you effectively tell it to forget that it is supposed to carry 1000 elements. Also D is allowed to reserve memory for future appends, so nested dynamic arrays may not align how you expect.

If you want to send multidimensional arrays to C, best use static arrays or a continuous dynamic array. Your example with static arrays:

```
void main()
{
    auto a = new double[3][1000];
    a[0] = [1, 2, 3];
    a[1] = [3, 4, 5];
    double* p = &(a[0][0]);
    for(size_t i=0; i<20; i++) {
        writef("%.0f ", *(p+i));
    }
    writeln;
}
```

Prints

```
1 2 3 3 4 5 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
```

Note that it is an array of a thousand [3] arrays, so [0] and [1] are adjacent.

**Edit to answer your edit:**

You have two options, both looking identical to C.

```
// dynamic array of double[3]
double[3][] a;

// or one-dimensional array
double[] a;

a.reserve(1000); // ensure space for 1000 new elements (use 3000 for the second option)

a ~= [3, 5, 7]; // works for both
// pass to C using a.ptr
```

Comment: These zeros are not really zeros, but rather uninitialized values - in the example I used the `double` type to see which numbers were initialized. But you are right, it was my assignment to the length property which changed the initial capacity, I took for granted that it should not.

Comment: Thank you, it works, although I find it strange that the order of indexes in `new double[3][1000]` is reversed compared to C syntax `double a[1000][3]` would be 1000 rows. One more question, though - will this array be allocated on the heap or on the stack?

Comment: As I said, the zeros in your GDC example are the length value and really zeroes. The length is never uninitialized. And it is stored next to the data in dynamic arrays. As for the syntax: if `double[3]` is an array of three doubles, `double[3][1000]` should be an array of a thousand `double[3]`s. Think of it as `(double[3])[1000]`. I wouldn't hold onto the C syntax too much, as there it isn't even written next to the type.

Comment: The same inconsistency is within D itself, shown at the top of my new example after edit; but of course it is not the syntax which is relevant here. As for the lengths, my knowledge about the guts of the D arrays is almost nil but I did check the first example without "%.0f" and also with `int` and `size_t` instead of `double` and I saw strange numbers in places where `double` values were truncated to 0 by my "%.0f" formatting. And there are no lengths next to rows in my second example, neither.

Comment: Oh well, I was also talking out of my realm there. Anyway, updated my answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Short and nice, especially the `a.ptr` hint. Now I have four ways which do work but I still do not know which are robust. The `double[][](rows,columns)` construction is not good because a seemingly innocent operation like the assignment to `a.length` property, which should *only* change the number of rows, changes the data layout completely behind the scenes. Is `double[3][]` better? I guess I am on my own to test and `assert`...

Answer (score 2):

OK, thanks to @weltensturm and with some more testing and reading the logic of D finally "clicked", so I summarize.

Basically, to rely on the multidimensional dynamic D arrays layout in memory, **all dimensions apart from the most outer one have to be static**, that is, known at compile time. These declarations:

```
double[3][] b;                // allocated on the stack, or
auto b = new double[3][](0);  // allocated on the heap
```

are both understood as dynamic arrays of (static arrays of length 3), and the size of rows is not allowed to change (but the number of rows yes):

```
b ~= [1,2,3];                 // works
b ~= [4,5,6,7.];              // Compilation error!
```

**That's the best guarantee of robustness one can get.**

So while using arrays declared as:

```
double a[];                   // or
double[][] a;                 //, or
auto a = new double[][](0,3); // these will be initial dimensions, not static!
```

is possible, **it is asking for trouble** because D runtime is allowed to change any dimension at any operation which change the contents of the array. For example, with any of the above declarations it is possible to append uneven rows:

```
a ~= [1,2,3];
a ~= [4,5,6,7.];              // accepted
```

and if it triggers memory reallocation, it will also more likely than not change the layout of data in memory.

As a side note, funny is the compiler error about this:

```
auto b = new double[3][];
Error: new can only create structs, dynamic arrays or class objects, not double[3][]'s
```

as it wasn't a dynamic array, while this:

```
auto b = new double[3][0];
```

is accepted and it makes an array with static number of columns and dynamic number of rows. Well...